# Magento 1.9 order review / email shows no items

Tags: magento, items

When an order is placed in my webshop there are no items shown in the "print order review" and "order email".

Yesterday I replaced the template/email files in frontend/base with the ones from the installation zip for 1.9.1 because I thought there was a problem when we upgraded from 1.8. After replacing the review and emails worked. Then I copied email/order/items/order/default.phtml to my theme to play around trying to get item thumbnails into order email. After 5 or 6 emails it stopped working again.

I don't have any idea where to look for the problem. Anybody any hints?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check if your module use default send email method Mage_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail()
- Magento uses for registered customers and guests different email templates. Do you have your issue with both groups of customers?
- Open System / Configuration / Sales Emails and check which template is used for New order? If there is something other than Default - try to set default and repeat email send.
- In default magento following things are used for order items output (look bellow). Try to search in your magento for handle `<sales_email_order_items>`, and if you find something instead of shown below, try to delete and recheck.

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales.xml

```
<!--
Email layouts section
-->
    <sales_email_order_items>
        <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
                <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
                <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
                <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
                    <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
    </sales_email_order_items>
```

- try to look through your templates from the layout (look above `email/order/items/order/default.phtml`)

**upd.1**

It could happened because all templates are getting from stack. Most probably in some higher lvl there is some template which overlay your necessary template. My advice is:

1. upload to your **app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales** correct templates from clean magento installation
2. upload correct template to `email/order/items/order/default.phtml`
3. remove all other templates from

> frontend/base/default/locale/{your new order templates}
>
> frontend/{package}/{theme}/locale/{your new order templates}
>
> frontend/{package}/default/locale/{your new order templates}
>
> frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/{your new order templates}
>
> frontend/{package}/default/locale/{your new order templates}

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated my first question with some additional information. I checked all your hints but everything looks good. As only registered users are allowed to place orders, I can't check guests. My custom theme doesn't use right now any of template/email files. Also with default layout the problem persists.

Comment: "After 5 or 6 emails it stopped working again." - I think following refers to one property which disallow send letter again if it was already sent. if ($this->getEmailSent()) { return $this; } (look in method sendNewOrderEmail()). You can temporarily remove this check. And please clarify your situation. Now items in order review are showing? You can't send emails?

Comment: Emails are always sending, but right now without items shown. As i described items showed up during 5 or 6 emails after I replaced app\design\frontend\base\default\template\email with files from 1.9.1 installation zip but after making changes to app/design/frontend/my_theme/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml they stopped showing up. Deleted that file in my theme but still not showing anymore

Comment: Why don't you revert changes to previous stage? If it worked properly.

Comment: I did! But unfortunately it doesn't help... I also replaced app\design\frontend\base\default\template\email files again but doesn't help anymore. Strange problem :-(

Comment: Thank you again for your hints, I really appreciate it. I followed steps 1+2 of your your update. Step 3 I couldn't as there is only 1 place where order templates are saved in my installation -> app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales (and de_DE for the german translation). Followed yours steps, cleared cache and tried with english shop but doesn't help, sorry

Comment: Ok, I can offer one more way. Try to determine which template file does magento use. Add some additional symbols to header. You need to detect which order_new.html and default.phtml are used. And then upload again files from default magento. To prevent such situations use some version control systems (for example .git). It can help to resolve such problems faster. The most probably you did some small fix somewhere which cause your problem. If its possible try to chech the difference between folders (of your current magento and clean magento) with WinMerge or another program.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. For now I have found a solution!! :-) In my custom sales.xml where some lines missing below the lines "tax/sales_order-tax". I have no answer why these lines are missing as I only deleted the "footer-links" in my sales.xml. Strange strange... I will now go on with the default.phtml to add thumbnails. I hope this time it will work better...

Comment: Glad to hear that you have found the solution. Anyway if you'd like to remove some block - better do it with <remove ... inside local.xml